# Swift Playing Audio Playlist in Background

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation

I have an audio app that I am working on that plays a list of audio files in the foreground and the background (locked screen). I am having a problem when playing through the audio playlist in the background.

Below is a function I loop through to play the playlist one audio file after the next. I seem to have a problem with my cellForItem everytime. If I don't unwrap it I get a fatal error. If I put it in an if let statement, the code doesn't run through it on the next reiteration when playing the next song. I never lose the indexPath so it should work just fine. I can't figure it out.

```
func playCellAudioInBackground(indexPath: IndexPath)  {
    if let item = cv.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {

    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 3 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [], animations: ({
            self.gradient.removeFromSuperlayer()
            item.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: item)
            self.view.setNeedsLayout()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }), completion: { (finished: Bool) in
            let audioURL = self.streams[indexPath.item][“audioURL"] as? String
            let isLive = self.streams[indexPath.item]["isLive"] as? Bool
            self.audioStreamSelected(audioUrl: audioURL!, live:isLive!) { (success) -> Void in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.audioPlay()
                }
            }
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two important things:

1. You shouldn't play or stream audio in the main thread. Use this thread for short operations, but mainly for UI updates.
2. You have to have a background task running in order to keep playing the audio when the application goes from the foreground to the background.

Check out [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started) neat tutorial where they precisely teach you about `Background Modes` and how to play audio in the background.

I hope this helps!